# XmlAdapter for list of dates

Tags: java, jaxb, adapter

I have the following class that includes a list of Date which I want to mashall. I have created the JaxBAdapter for the Date class, but it seems it is not called.

I think the problem is the fact that I'm using a list and not just a Date variable.

Could you give me some hint on how should I code the adapter or annotate the class so each element of the list is mashalled using the adapter?

Will it work for JSON serialization as well? I'm planning to use this classes on my REST webservice.

**Root.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

  @XmlElementWrapper(name="timePeriods")
  @XmlElement(name = "timePeriod")
  @JsonProperty(value = "timePeriod")
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = JaxBDateThreadSafeAdapter.class, type = Date.class)
  private List<Date> timePeriod;

  public Root() {
    this(new ArrayList<String>(), new ArrayList<Date>(2));
  }

  public Root(List<Date> timePeriod) {
    this.timePeriod = new ArrayList<Date>(timePeriod);
  }  
}
```

**JaxBAdapter**

```
public class JaxBDateThreadSafeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

  /**
   * Thread safe {@link DateFormat}.
   */
  private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> DATE_FORMAT_TL =
          new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {

            @Override
            protected DateFormat initialValue() {
              // return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                  // ISO 8601 format
              return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
            }

          };

  @Override
  public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
    return DATE_FORMAT_TL.get().format(v);
  }

  @Override
  public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
    return DATE_FORMAT_TL.get().parse(v);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` works as such with `java.util.List` as well. But the problem in the adapter class is the date format that is used. `JAXB` (atleast 2.x onwards) is not strict and dont report such errors and quietly suppresses it.

```
return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

change to

```
return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```